# Return value not being passed to other function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to brush up on my JavaScript by doing some exercises.

I wrote a `range` function that takes two arguments, start and end, and returns an array containing all the numbers from start up to (and including) end.

Then I wrote a `sum` function that takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of these numbers.

The problem is when I'm returning a value from `range` and passing to `sum` on line 27(Or `console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));`). However I'm getting zero as the return value. I check my `sum` function by passing the array `test` and it worked as expected. What am I overlooking?

```
function range(start, end, step){
  if(step === undefined){ step = 1; }

  var arr = [];

  for(var i = start; i >= end; i += step){
    arr.push(i);   
  }

  return arr;
}

function sum(nums){
    var total = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
     total += nums[i];
    }

    return total;
}
var test = [1, 3, 5];
console.log(sum(test));
// → returns 9


console.log(range(5, 2, -1));
// → returns [5, 4, 3, 2]

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// → should return 55, but returns 0
```

Comment: Probz want `typeof step === 'undefined'`.

Comment: what do you get when you do console.log(range(1,10));  That is more helpful in narrowing this down than the other one you wrote.  ie.  If that returns [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] then the issue is in sum().  Otherwise the issue is in range().

Comment: `range(1,10)` returns 0 @DanB.

Comment: So the issue is with the range() function.  So it works for decrementing values with a step.  But it doesn't work for incrementing values with no step.  Now try narrowing it down further.  What's range(1,10,2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `range` function has an issue in its for-loop condition. Here's what I got to work that also handles descending ranges:

```
function range(start, end, step){
  if(step === undefined){ step = 1; }

  var c = (Math.max(start, end) - Math.min(end, start)) / Math.abs(step);
  var arr = [];

  for(var i = start; c-- >= 0; i += step){
    arr.push(i);   
  }

  return arr;
}
```

It adds a counter `c` for the amount of steps to take, decrements it until it's less than 0 and doesn't worry with `i` or `end`.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syssqob4/2/

Comment: But then it fails with a negative step.

Comment: @Scimonster thanks for catching that, updated to account for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your `for` loop.

```
for(var i = start; i >= end; i += step){
   arr.push(i);
}
```

This assumes that `step` is always negative, and that `start` is always greater than `end`.

The minimum change you can do to your code to make it work is the following. You don't HAVE TO do the type check (making sure step is a number) but it's good practice not to assume the user is always following your assumptions (I didn't do the type check for `start` and `end`). For example you yourself didn't follow the assumption of step being negative.

```
if (isNaN(parseFloat(step))) // This makes sure step is a numeric variable
    return arr;

if (step == 0) // This makes sure that the for loop won't be an infinite loop
    return arr;

if (step > 0) // This makes sure that step is going to be a negative value
    step = -1 * step;

if (start < end) { // This makes sure that start is always greater than end
    var tmp = end;
    end = start;
    start = tmp;
}

for(var i = start; i >= end; i += step){
   arr.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking to make sure start is greater than end.  This is always the case if you are incrementing.  You should make sure you have the right order first before going into the loop.  Then you can always loop from low to high.

You also have competing concepts of what the step is, versus start and end.  Step should only take positive integers.  If the start is lower than the end, you know to step down.  If you want to make it more robust then just add this:  `int step = Math.abs(step);`

```
int low;
int high;

if(start < end) {
    low = start;
    high = end;
}
else {
    low = end;
    high = start;
}

for(var i = low; i >= high; i += step){
   arr.push(i);   
}
```